# Tapping on one notification clears all the other notification from the same app - Phonegap Plugin Push

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have implemented Push using this [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

Now when I have multiple notifications with different `notId`, and I tap on one of them, the event handler is called but the other notifications vanish from the notifications tray.

This particular issue seems to be open at the [Github](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/525) page of the older version of the same plugin.

Following is my code:

```
  var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {"senderID": "XXXXXXX" ,"icon": "ic_transey1",
            "iconColor": "grey"},
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {}
    });

    push.on('registration', function (data) {
        console.log('device token ',data.registrationId);
        window.localStorage.setItem("UserDeviceID", data.registrationId);
    });

    push.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    push.on('notification', function (data) {
        console.log('notification event');
        navigator.notification.confirm(
                data.message,
                function (buttonIndex) {
                    onConfirm(buttonIndex, data);
                },
                data.title,
                ['Dismiss','Ok']
        );

/* at first I thought setApplicationIconBadgeNumber is causing the issue, 
but commenting the below code didnt help either */

        /*push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
            console.log('success in clearin');
        }, function() {
            console.log('error');
        }, 0);*/
    });
```

I tried commenting the `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` in the bottom, but didnt help.

Any fix/workaround for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967944/tapping-on-one-notification-clears-all-the-other-notification-from-the-same-app doesnt help i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the option `clearNotifications` is default to `true` for Android, which clears all the notifications.
Set it to  `clearNotifications:false` for Android, and it will work fine.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1015
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions